# Getting Subgurim Map Marker Position in Button Click Event

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, c#-3.0, subgurim-maps

I am using Subgurim Map for Setting Marker based on inputed Address. Using GMarker, I am able to load it into Map.

Now this address might be wrong or nearby actual address. So that I am giving opportunity to customer to set actual address with different Marker ( which is bubbled when a button called "Pick Bubble" button )

like,

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(txtAddress.Text.Trim());
        sb.AppendFormat(", {0}", txtCity.Text.Trim());
        sb.AppendFormat("- {0}", txtZipcode.Text.Trim());
        sb.Append(", Gujarat");
        sb.AppendFormat(", {0}", txtCountry.Text.Trim());

        GetAddressCordinates googleCordinate = new GetAddressCordinates(Constants.APP_SETTINGS.GoogleMapAPIKey);
        Coordinate cordinate = googleCordinate.GetCoordinates(sb.ToString());

        GLatLng gLatLng = new GLatLng();
        {
            gLatLng.lat = double.Parse(cordinate.Latitude.ToString());
            gLatLng.lng = double.Parse(cordinate.Longitude.ToString());
        }

        if (gLatLng != null)
        {
            GMarker gMarker;

            GIcon gIcon = new GIcon();
            gIcon.image = ResolveUrl(string.Format("~/Images/ActualFlag.png"));
            gIcon.shadow = ResolveUrl(string.Format("~/Images/Shadow.png"));
            gIcon.shadowSize = new GSize(30, 30);
            gIcon.iconSize = new GSize(24, 24);

            GMarkerOptions mOpts = new GMarkerOptions();
            mOpts.draggable = true;
            mOpts.RaiseOnDrag = true;
            mOpts.Animation = GMarkerOptions.AnimationType.Bounce;
            mOpts.icon = gIcon;

            gMarker = new GMarker(gLatLng, mOpts);

            GInfoWindow infoWindow = new GInfoWindow(gMarker, "", false);

            GMap1.addInfoWindow(infoWindow);
            //GMap1.addGMarker(gMarker);

            string jsFunction = string.Format("function(){{ var ev = new serverEvent('dragend', 0); ev.addArg({0}.getPoint().lat()); ev.addArg({0}.getPoint().lng()); ev.send(); }}", gMarker.ID);

            GListener listener = new GListener(gMarker.ID, GListener.Event.dragend, "alertame");
            GMap1.Add(listener);
            GMap1.setCenter(gLatLng);
        }
```

Now I want this two marker position into Button called "NEXT" for manipulate.

How I will get Marker positions ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to put it into `GinfoWindow` ?
As a string as follows:

```
 dir= "<input type='button' name='next'>"
```

into:

```
 GInfoWindow infoWindow = new GInfoWindow(gMarker, dir, false);
```